# Dynamic route prevents redirecting to 404 page in Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a `[pid].js` file in my Next.js project. I also wanted to implement a custom 404 page but here is the problem: I put `404.js` file inside `/pages` directory. If I delete my `[pid].js` file, 404 page works just fine. But, if I keep my `[pid].js` file, the first request goes into pids, and since the url does not match any of the pages defined in pids, I get an error. Should I explicitly return my 404 component from pids? Is this a good practice?

Here is the code (which does not redirect to 404 page right now):

`[pid].js`

```js
const Pid = ({ url, props }) => {
    const getPages = () => {
        let component = null;
        switch (url) {
            case 'checkout':
                component = <CheckoutPage {...props} />;
                break;
            //other switch cases...
            default:
                //should I return my 404 component here?
                component = <DefaultPage {...props} />;
        }
        return component;
    };

    return getPages();
};

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const res = await getReq(`/getUrl`, 'content', context);

    switch (res.url) {
        case 'checkout': {
            return {
                props: {
                    url: res.url,
                    props: {
                    ... //my other props
                    },
                },
            };
        }
        default:
            return {
                props: null,
            };
    }
}

Pid.propTypes = {
    url: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default Pid;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From Next.js 10, you can return `notFound: true` from your `getServerSideProps` to trigger a 404 page.

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const res = await getReq(`/getUrl`, 'content', context);
    switch (res.url) {
        case 'checkout': {
            return {
                props: {
                    //my other props
                },
            };
        }
        default:
            return {
                notFound: true
            };
    }
}
```

I've placed it in the `default` case as an example, but feel free to return it at any other point/condition.

Answer (score 26):

From NextJS 10 onwards, you don't have to return your 404 page explicitly thanks to the new flag `notFound: true`.
You can use it at `getStaticProps` and `getServerSideProps` to auto trigger the default 404 page or your own custom 404 page as well.

Check out these examples from NextJS Docs.

```js
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const res = await fetch(`https://.../data`)
  const data = await res.json()

  if (!data) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    }
  }

  return {
    props: { data }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const res = await fetch(`https://...`)
  const data = await res.json()

  if (!data) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    }
  }

  return {
    props: {}, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```

#### Doc References

1. [notfound Support on Nextjs10](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-10#notfound-support)
2. [notfound on getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation)
3. [notfound on getserversideprops](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering)
4. [Custom 404 Page](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page#404-page)