# NextJs Server-Side-Rendering Error Handle?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

How can i handle SSR errors ?
Let's say the API is broken and request result is 404. How can i handle ? What can i do ?
I Have no idea can you guide me please.

My Code :

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { data } = await getAllBurger();
  return {
    props: { burgers: data },
  };
}
```

Comment: Do you want to display the 404 page if the API errors? If so, you can simply return `{ notFound: true }` from `getServerSideProps`. See [Dynamic route prevents redirecting to 404 page in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65965827/dynamic-route-prevents-redirecting-to-404-page-in-next-js).

Comment: I dont want to display 404 page. Let's say  getAllBurger api is not working.  How can i manage the page ? I have to say to user, Please try again later or something notification on the front

Comment: You can pass an additional prop in `props` that tells you the API call failed, then handle that accordingly in your React code to display what you want to the user.